# call model in zend form using dependencies + zend framework 2

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I am trying to fetch my category model in zend form for working out with select element with zend framework 2.

after lot of code searching I found I can either inject or pull dependencies.

Following code I did in my module.php

I want categoryTable.php(model) file in my CategoryForm.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Category\Model\CategoryTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('CategoryTableGateway');
                $table = new CategoryTable($tableGateway);
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($table);echo "</pre>";
                return $table;
            },
            'CategoryTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Category());
                return new TableGateway('Of_Restaurants_Category', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'Category\Form\CategoryForm' => function ($sm) {
                $service = $sm->get('Category\Model\CategoryTable');
                $form    = new Form;
                $form->setService($service);
                return $form;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

then I put following code in my controller.

```
 $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("Category\Form\CategoryForm");
```

Then I Put following code in my CategoryForm.php

```
public function getCategoryTable()
{
    if (!$this->categoryTable) {

        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $this->categoryTable = $sm->get('Category\Model\CategoryTable');
    }
    return $this->categoryTable;
}
```

And then I call it in same file like this way

```
public function __construct($name = null)
{

   parent::__construct('category');
   echo "<pre>";print_r($this->getCategoryTable());die;

   .... other code
```

I found this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Category\Form\CategoryForm::getServiceLocator() in D:\wamp\www\zendapp\module\Category\src\Category\Form\CategoryForm.php on line 120
```

please help. and am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure that CategoryForm implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and required functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

Step :1

Here is my module.php code

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(

            'Category\Form\CategoryForm' => 'Category\Form\CategoryForm',

        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'Category\Model\CategoryTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('CategoryTableGateway');
                $table = new CategoryTable($tableGateway);
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($table);echo "</pre>";
                return $table;
            },
            'CategoryTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Category());
                return new TableGateway('Of_Restaurants_Category', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Step :2

Then in controller I made this change

```
  // $form = new CategoryForm();
  // Service locator now injected
  $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Category\Form\CategoryForm');
```

Step :3

Then In my categoryForm.php I made below changes

```
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
```

protected $serviceManager;

```
public function getCategoryTable()
{
    if (!$this->categoryTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceManager();
        $this->categoryTable = $sm->get('Category\Model\CategoryTable');
    }
    return $this->categoryTable;
}

protected function getCatList()
{

    $groups = $this->getCategoryTable()->fetchAll();
    return $groups;
}

public function getServiceManager()
{
    if ( is_null($this->serviceManager) ) {
        throw new Exception('The ServiceManager has not been set.');
    }

    return $this->serviceManager;
}

public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
{
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    // Call the init function of the form once the service manager is set
    $this->init();
    return $this;
} 
public function __construct($name = null) // constructor I finished immediately
{
    parent::__construct('category');
}
```

I add INIT() function to fetch servicemanager

```
public function init()
{
   $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
   $options = array();
    foreach ($this->getCatList() as $cat) {
        $options[$cat->id] = $cat->title;
    }

    $this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
         'name' => 'parent_id',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Parent Category',
             'empty_option' => 'Please choose Parent Category',
              'value_options' => $options,
         ),

    ));
}
```

Hope this will help who are new ZF2.